# Why grid renders into the other grid row?

Tags: php, user-interface, frameworks, atk4

Why does the second grid renders into the first grid row, once I click on the X to clear the quicksearch?
What am I doing wrong?
This is my page:

```
class page_alumnos_equipo extends Page {
function init(){
    parent::init();



    $this->api->stickyGET('id');

    $mAlumno=$this->add('Model_Alumno')->loadData($_GET['id']);       
    $h=$this->add('H1')->set($mAlumno->get('name').' ( '.$mAlumno->get('grado').$mAlumno->get('nivel'). ' )');

    $this->add('H2')->set('Equipos actuales');
    $ins=$this->add('MVCGrid');
    $ins->setModel('Equipo',array('clase'));
    $ins->dq->where('alumno_id',$_GET['id']);

    $this->add('H2')->set('Agregar a Nuevo Equipo');
    $g=$this->add('MVCGrid');
    $g->setModel('Clase');
    $g->getColumn('name')->makeSortable();
    $g->dq->order('dia_id');
    $g->dq->order('hora');
    $g->dq->order('grado_id');
    $qs=$g->addQuickSearch(array('name','grado','dia','hora','asesor'));      

    if($qs->recall('q')==''){
      $qs->memorize('q',$mAlumno->get('grado'));
    }

    $f=$this->add('Form');
    $f->addField('line','selected');
    $g->addSelectable($f->getElement('selected'));

    $f->addSubmit();        
    if ($f->isSubmitted()){
        $selected=json_decode($f->get('selected'));

        foreach($selected as $sel){

            $this->api->db->dsql()->table('equipo')
                ->set('alumno_id',$_GET['id'])
                ->set('clase_id',$sel)
                ->do_insert();
        }
        $this->js()
                ->univ()
                ->closeDialog()
                ->successMessage('Se asignó equipo a: '.$mAlumno->get('name'))
                ->execute();
    }
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: just a suggestion, but add a second argument to add('MVCGrid',xxx) with some unique identifier. No spaces, [a-z]

Answer (score 0):

while i don't see any problem with your page, it could be an object/region rendering issue.

for me, as much as possible, i try not to call the univ or jquery javascript of the page's view but rather only of a specific object's view. so instead of this:

```
 $this->js()
    ->univ()
    ->closeDialog()
    ->successMessage('Se asignó equipo a: '.$mAlumno->get('name'))
    ->execute();
```

make the javascript call specific to an object by changing it to:

```
 $f->js()
    ->univ()
    ->closeDialog()
    ->successMessage('Se asignó equipo a: '.$mAlumno->get('name'))
    ->execute();
```

i hope this solves your object rendering issue.